# add payloads during indexing and searching with lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have a function that calculates a different local IDF for each term in a document (tweet) afterwards I want to integrate this function when indexing and also when searching using a payloads (lucene) is it possible to do this and so Do you have any examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this possible, you can see an example of payload processing during index and search phase on following article [Getting Started with Payloads.](https://lucidworks.com/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/.)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do it.

Comment: I have another question in my case I have a function that calculates a different score for each term I should insert in the index I know I should use payload but I have no idea how to do it! If you can help me?